# How to rotate data by converting rows to columns using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I wrote the following query **to rotate data by converting rows to columns** using LINQ:

```
var query = from p in context.PrivilegesTable
            group p by p.Type into g
            select new Privileges
            {
                Type = g.Key,
                AllowRead = g.Any(p => p.Seq == 1),
                AllowAdd = g.Any(p => p.Seq == 2)
                AllowEdit = g.Any(p => p.Seq == 3)
                AllowDelete = g.Any(p => p.Seq == 4)
            };
```

I think there's a better way to implement it. for more details, read the following:

I have the following Privileges table:

```
      Type    Seq
        1       1
        2       1
        2       2
        3       1
        3       2
        3       3
```

And the following Privileges class:

```
class Privileges
{
   public int ID { get; set; }

   public Type Type { get; set;}

   public int AllowRead { get; set; } // when sequence = 1 
   public int AllowAdd { get; set; } // when sequence = 2
   public int AllowEdit { get; set; } // when sequence = 3
   public int AllowDelete { get; set; } // when sequence = 4
}
```

Now, I want to create a `List<Prvileges>` using LINQ to have the following result:

[Type, AllowRead, AllowAdd, AllowEdit, AllowDelete]

[1, True, False, False, False]

[2, True, True, False, False]

[3, True, True, True, False]

Is my query bad for performance ?
Is there a better one ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a `enum` to represent the privileges you can have.

```
[Flags]
enum Privilege
{
    None = 0,
    Read = 1,
    Add = 2,
    Edit = 4,
    Delete = 8,
}
```

In that way you can store a single value to represent all your privileges. Then your Privileges class would be like this:

```
class Privileges {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set;}
    private Privilege m_Privileges;

    public bool AllowRead {
        get { return HasPrivilege(Privilege.Read); }
        set { CheckPrivilege(Privilege.Read, value); }
    }

    public bool AllowAdd {
        get { return HasPrivilege(Privilege.Add); }
        set { CheckPrivilege(Privilege.Add, value); }
    }

    public bool AllowEdit {
        get { return HasPrivilege(Privilege.Edit); }
        set { CheckPrivilege(Privilege.Edit, value); }
    }

    public bool AllowDelete {
        get { return HasPrivilege(Privilege.Delete); }
        set { CheckPrivilege(Privilege.Delete, value); }
    }

    private bool HasPrivilege(Privilege p) {
        return (m_Privileges & p) == p;
    }

    private void CheckPrivilege(Privilege p, bool owns) {
        if (owns)
            m_Privileges = m_Privileges | p;
        else
            m_Privileges = m_Privileges & (~p);
    }
}
```

Of course this approach is only valid if you have a limited and known number of privileges.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the data is stored, I just want to write the best LINQ query to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Your query performance will be abysmal because every Any does a join (L2S implementation problem). In SQL you would do a pivot clause. It can be simulated in L2S but the join problem remains (I reported this bug today on connect). There is no workaround to my knowledge, sorry. If perf is a problem, you must cache or use raw sql.

Edit: I think I have found a special case for you problem:

```
var query = from p in context.PrivilegesTable
            let shift = 1 << p.Seq
            group shift by p.Type into g
            select new
            {
                Type = g.Key,
                AllowMask = g.Sum(),
            };
```

How cool is that? ;-) Unfortunately it is terrible code and works only up to 64 bit flags.

Comment: You sure it's not possible to avoid the multiple joins with 2 .Select()?